# 統計ソフトRにおいて、あるパッケージをインストールすることがきません。

Tags: r

統計ソフトRにおいて、
lmeパッケージをインストールしようとすると
以下のエラーがでます。解決策を教えてください。

```
install.packages("lme")
Installing package into ‘C:/＊＊＊＊/＊＊＊＊＊＊/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lme’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
```

Comment: lmeは[CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme/index.html)からは削除されていますね。またこのメッセージについては、英語版SOの[質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/5546006)にてまとめられています。

Comment: 本当ですか？有益な情報をありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

最新のパッケージは"lme4"([Package ‘lme4’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf))だと思います。

lme4パッケージがインストールできませんか？

Comment: lme4についてはインストールできます。しかし、lmeをつかった他のパッケージを使うことが目的なのでlmeをつかいたいのです。

Comment: 本ではnlmeをつかうとなっていました。私の早合点で勝手なパッケージ名を作ってしまいました。回答くださりありがとうございます。